# what happend when sending ping to 192.168.1.255 or 255.255.255.255

Tags: networking

what happend when sending ping or packet to 192.168.255.255 or 255.255.255.255?

i know its sending to all network or to all subnet network but

its sending the packet to all 65,534 ip addresses in a second?

how this is working?

and i see in the arp list that

192.168.255.255 and 255.255.255.255 have the same mac FF:FF:FF:FF:FF , how so ?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> its sending the packet to all 65,534 ip addresses in a second?

No, it's sending **one** packet to **one** IP address. "Broadcast" means that the *network* takes care of duplicating it to all connected devices, but it's still sent to a single address.

- On modern switched Ethernet, normally the switch would forward the MAC frame to whichever Ethernet port corresponds to the destination MAC address. When the switch sees `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF` as the destination address, it recognizes this as a broadcast and forwards copies of it to *all* ports, with one copy per port.

  So in the end it's not "1 packet per IP address" but rather "1 copy of the (same) packet per physical device".
- On networks that are inherently broadcast, such as Wi-Fi or old coax Ethernet, all frames already travel to all devices; the hosts just ignore frames with an unrecognized destination. But all hosts recognize the "broadcast" MAC address `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF` and accept the packet within.

> 192.168.255.255 and 255.255.255.255 have the same mac FF:FF:FF:FF:FF , how so ?

The IPv4 specification just *defines* that the "local broadcast" and "subnet broadcast" IP addresses have the same destination MAC address. It is not resolved via ARP unlike regular addresses; it's set by specification.

Broadcast aside, though, it is *completely normal* for a single interface to have multiple IP addresses, and therefore for multiple IP addresses to resolve to the same MAC address. You could easily have 10 IPs with the same MAC, all leading to the same system.

Comment: That's not what the option is for. The system always treats the local subnet broadcast addresses specially, and ping will tell you as much if you try to ping that address; the `-b` option is there to *bypass the safety check* for historical reasons.